# firefox: how do you uninstall an add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

have installed `Web Developer` on `Firefox 5.0` and personally found it redundant.  would like to remove it.  `Tools -&gt; Add-Ons` only *adds* add-ons, but does not remove.  is there any way to get rid of it?

btw, this is seems like such a dumb question, but heaven help me I cannot find how to do this simple task.

from menu, have Tools > Add-Ons, but that is a web page that only has ability to *add* add-ons, not remove them.

running on Ubuntu, so menu structure might be different than MS

---

problem was that I was following `Add-On's`, which is a web page for finding and installing Add-Ons.  the option `Extensions` shows installed Add-Ons and allows their removal.  - my stupid (thankfully)

Comment: belongs on http://superuser.com/ ... probably that's why you got downvoted

Comment: @Quamis - thanks - was unaware of superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an addon / extenstion - goto Firefox > options > add-ons - then from the left menu select "Extensions" select the extension to remove and click "Remove" ... i just tested with Firebug and it does the job ....

Comment: cannot follow you.  have Firefox > Tools, but no Firefox > Options - from Tools > Add-Ons, but that's a web page that has no means of removing an Add-On

Comment: Im using Firefox 5 - what version are you running ?

Comment: ok - was being overly stupid - was following Add-Ons instead of Extensions @ManseUK - thanks for forcing me to read again!

Comment: @cc ... no probs ... glad you managed to fix your problem :-)